# search file and then return part of the line below

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use PowerShell to search a file for a string then return part of the string that is on the next line.

The file would be like: LTI.ini

```
Division=AAA-
TargetContainer=OU=Computers,OU=123,DC=ms,DC=com

Division=BBB-
TargetContainer=OU=Computers,OU=456,DC=ms,DC=com
```

So I have so far is

```
$name = 'BBB-1234'
$pos = $name.IndexOf("-")
$leftPart = $name.Substring(0, $pos) + '-'

$a = Get-Content ..\Desktop\Powershell\LTI.ini
$b = $a | Select-String $leftPart
$b
```

This gives me $b as the BBB- line from the LTI.ini, but I don't know how to set the following line to a variable, and then only grab everything after TargetContainer=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
$b =($a | select-string $leftpart -Context 1  ).context.postcontext -replace '(?:TargetContainer=)(.*)','$1'
$b
```

Comment: +1 Not knowing about context, I was thinking about regular expression accross multiple lines.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly.

I tried using -context but it didn't seem like it was treating it as a string that I could store the output from. I was using something like -Context 0,1 which would display the line from my pattern match and the line below it, but then I could figure out how to just use the line below :) 

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the multiline regex @JPBlanc mentioned:

```
$regex = "${leftPart}(.+)(TargetContainer=)(.+)Division="
[regex]::Matches($a, $regex, 'Singleline')[0].Groups[3].Value.Trim()
```

Comment: That will not work for the last one in the file.:-) Try this instead: $a = (Get-Content *file_spec_here*) -join "`n"; $regex = "${leftPart}.*$\s*TargetContainer=(.+?)$"; [regex]::Matches($a, $regex, 'Multiline')[0].Groups[1].Value.Trim()

Comment: Thank you, I will look at that too. I was trying to figure out regex but couldn't get it.

Comment: msorens way works also, but I think since it's a reply I cannot mark it as an answer too. Thank you to everyone that replied.

Comment: @msorens You could also just give it a tail. `$a += "Division="`. That would make it work.

Comment: True, @Andy, but I have a (strong) preference for the pattern to match just the current record (rather than also including the first part of the subsequent record). Just seems cleaner to me; perhaps due to some childhood trauma I had... :-)